# MySQL Timestamp Difference Day Incorrect

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I made such a query. Except for the day, they all calculate correctly. How can I fix it?

```
SELECT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2017-10-13 16:57:27', NOW()) > 0, 
          CONCAT(
              TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), ' yıl ',
              MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 12), ' ay ',
              FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 30.4375)), ' gün ',
              MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 24), ' saat ',
              MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' dakika ',
              MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' saniye'
            ),

        IF(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 12) > 0, 
            CONCAT(
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 12), ' ay ',
                FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 30.4375)), ' gün ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 24), ' saat ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' dakika ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' saniye'
            ),

        IF(FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 30.4375)) > 0, 
            CONCAT(
                FLOOR(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 30.4375)), ' gün ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 24), ' saat ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' dakika ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' saniye'
            ),

        IF(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 24) > 0, 
            CONCAT(
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 24), ' saat ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' dakika ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' saniye'
            ),

        IF(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60) > 0, 
            CONCAT(
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' dakika ',
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' saniye'
            ),

        IF(MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60) > 0, 
            CONCAT(
                MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2011-01-19 16:57:27', NOW()), 60), ' saniye'
            ),

        'Yok'))))))
AS time
```

Output: 9 yıl 4 ay 28 gün 18 saat 6 dakika 13 saniye

Expected: 9 yıl 4 ay 29 gün 18 saat 6 dakika 13 saniye

Comment: Try using `current_timestamp()` instead of `now()` as timestamp counts for timezone but DateTime doesn't

Comment: '9 yıl 4 ay 29 gün 18 saat 6 dakika 13 saniye' - what's that now?

Comment: @RusArtM The problem is not related to it. I have the same problem when I write it myself.

Comment: Month may contain 28..31 day. None month contains 30.4375 days. This is a source of your problem, and it cannot be solved using your algorithm.

Comment: @P.Salmon Day (Gün in turkish) not equal. Normally 29 but in query give me 28

Comment: @Akina I found this unit conversion on the internet.

Comment: This algorithm is approximate, so it is not applicable when you need in accurate result.

Comment: @Akina I need an accurate result. How can I do it?

Comment: Your result cannot be accurate. Because the same difference value (timestamp difference in second) must produce different result depends on the date in source data. But if you want then you must use the next algo: get the difference in years X between source date A and current date, add X years to A and get date B, get the difference in months Y between date B and current date, add Y months to B and get date C, then get the difference between date С and current date and convert it to days/hours/minutes/seconds using the rest of your algorithm.

Comment: @Akina Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: @RusArtM *Try using current_timestamp() instead of now() as timestamp counts for timezone but DateTime doesn't* [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) claims that *CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() are synonyms for NOW().*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @start = '2011-01-19 16:57:27';
SET @finish = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,   @start,                                                          @finish) diff_years,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  @start + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,   @start, @finish) YEAR,   @finish) diff_months,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,    @start + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  @start, @finish) MONTH,  @finish) diff_days,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,   @start + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,    @start, @finish) DAY,    @finish) diff_hours,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @start + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,   @start, @finish) HOUR,   @finish) diff_minutes,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @start + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @start, @finish) MINUTE, @finish) diff_seconds
;
```